# Change the html page using a Processing function

Tags: javascript, html, processing

I have a Processing sketch that I want to embed in a landing page inside a  that will prompt the user to press a button and enter the site.
The function to receive the mouse click is inside the Processing file but needs to change the displayed html page - how can I do this?

```
<html><head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>Landing page before the main site</title>
    <script src="processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
    <canvas id="lander" data-processing-sources="lander/lander.pde"></canvas>
</body></html>
```

And the Processing sketch has the function:

```
void mousePressed(){
    if(overBox){
         // push the displayed page to home.html
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from being a terrible idea because you've now locked away what should be web functionality into a canvas (this is what we hate about Flash, too), you're in JavaScript context, so you can just call `window.location = "http://....";` and it'll work.

That said, there is absolutely no reason to do what you're about to do here. An HTML5 `<a href=realpage.html">button label</a>` and CSS to style it to look like your button is all you need, using Processing is plain old "you'r doing it wrong" in this instance.

Comment: Thing is I was going to use the processing sketch to have a non-static web page, I know I can style a button but I wanted to create an animated page in Processing. - However I thank you for your answer!

Comment: you weren't. You wanted to create an interactive graphical program that happened to be able to open URLs in a browser. I understand the appeal of making the sketch itself do navigation, but that just hides "browsing behaviour" in a container that isn't itself a browser, and isn't accessible to the browser either. It's why flash sites are so horrible, too.

Comment: Right - I guess I'll go learn more JavaScript to achieve the aesthetic I wanted instead of using Processing? 
How can I put a polygon underneath the html button...

Comment: ... that way? Draw all the gorgeous graphics you want, and have an actual button overlaid. With an onclick, and a tabindex=0, and css opacity:0, and when you need that button, you use something like http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html#interface to make your sketch tell your on-page JS it's time to make that button active so that when people click, clicks happen. Effort? Maybe. Infinitely better than the modern equivalent of a Flash nav? Definitely. Alternatively, pretty sure the new [p5.js](http://p5js.org) can do this without too much work already, but I can't confirm that atm.